# UpdatePanel works when viewing page, but not when inside iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iframe, updatepanel

Currently, I have a dropdown menu that, when an item is selected, dynamically populates another dropdownmenu. This works completely fine when viewing the page by itself, however, When I am viewing the page inside an iframe, nothing happens when I change options in the drop down menu. The main page that contains the iframe, also has an updatePanel, and I feel there might be some sort of routing issue? Maybe the update cannot differentiate between the panels and is being routed to the panel in the main page? Any help appreciated!

The code on the main page looks identical as in the main page, I am creating an item, while in the framed page, I am updating an item.

**edit: UPDATE**
I made a test page with nothing on it except for the iframe, and it still doesn't work. Seems like the updatepanel simply does not work when loaded inside the iframe for me.

**aspx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <li>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="CategorySelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CategorySelector_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--Please Select--" Value="none"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Everything"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Product"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Brand"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Category"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="SubCategory"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="CategorySelector" ForeColor="#FF3300" InitialValue="none">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </li>
         <li>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ItemSelector" runat="server">
           </asp:DropDownList></li>   
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**code:**

```
protected void CategorySelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (CategorySelector.Text == "Product")
        {
            ItemSelector.DataSource = Product.GetAllActive();
            ItemSelector.DataTextField = "Name";
            ItemSelector.DataValueField = "ID";
            ItemSelector.DataBind();
        }
        if (CategorySelector.Text == "Category")
        {
            ItemSelector.DataSource = Category.GetAllActive();
            ItemSelector.DataTextField = "Name";
            ItemSelector.DataValueField = "ID";
            ItemSelector.DataBind();
        }
        if (CategorySelector.Text == "SubCategory")
        {
            ItemSelector.DataSource = SubCategory.GetAllActive();
            ItemSelector.DataTextField = "Name";
            ItemSelector.DataValueField = "ID";
            ItemSelector.DataBind();
        }
        if (CategorySelector.Text == "Brand")
        {
            ItemSelector.DataSource = Brand.GetAllActive();
            ItemSelector.DataTextField = "Name";
            ItemSelector.DataValueField = "ID";
            ItemSelector.DataBind();
        }
        if (CategorySelector.Text == "Everything")
        {
            ItemSelector.Items.Clear();
            ItemSelector.Items.Add("Everything");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been my use of fancybox to iframe the page. I forgot to add the type iframe to the fancy box settings, which caused the entire page to render inline.

```
$(".modify").fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe'
});
```

adding the type iframe as per above fixes the issue.

Comment: It's always the little things :)